# Expectance of random variable by different (but related) distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Do we have any relation between 
$$\mathbb{E}_X[\lvert X \rvert^2] = \int \lvert X \rvert^2 f_X(x) dx$$

and 
$$\mathbb{E}_{\lvert X \rvert^2}[\lvert X \rvert^2] = \int z f_Z(z) dz$$ where $Z = \lvert X \rvert^2$?

Can I apply [Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)?

Comment: Yes they are exactly the same by law of the unconscious statistician.

Comment: @BGM thanks but how can I apply the law? The law said that $\mathbb{E}_X[z] = \int z dF_X(x)$ that seems different from $\mathbb{E}_Z[z] = \int z f_Z(z)dz = \int z dF_z(z)$

Comment: @CathMaillon The law implies $E[g(X)] = \int g(x) f_X(x) \, dx$. The definition of expectation implies $E[g(X)] = \int z f_{g(X)}(z) \, dz$.